# OpenJDK and com.sun.net

Tags: eclipse, java

I am looking at using HttpsConfigurator, HttpsServer, and HttpContext in the com.sun.net package.  Additionally, part of my project requirement is to use OpenJDK.

I am coding in Eclipse, which will not auto import anything from the com.sun.net package, because it is considered 'forbidden'.  After enabling forbidden packages, I can get everything working, building and running.  My question, what is considered safe to use in OpenJDK?  I am under the impression that it is just the java.* and javax.* packages.

I downloaded the OpenJDK 7 source, and I see that com.sun.net is part of the source, which implies that my assumption might be incorrect.  I haven't had any luck googling yet, and I was hoping one the experts here can fill in the missing pieces.

In recap, what is considered safe to use in OpenJDK? Why would Eclipse label com.sun.net as 'forbidden'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Countless documents -- books, articles, tutorials, official JDK documentation -- have explained that the com.sun.* packages are implementation details, subject to change or removal at any time; they are not intended for user programs. They are not portable, not reliably present, and possibly not as robust as actual API classes. In general, if the JDK documentation bundle contains Javadoc for it, it's intended for your use; otherwise not.

Comment: Boom, thanks for the extra keywords, I was able to find this that clarified it: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html.  Again, many thanks for the reply!