# Is every code based on Oracle working with OpenJDK?

Tags: java, compatibility

I would like to know, how can I find the main differences between OracleJDK and OpenJDK. I still don´t get the whole difference between them if it comes to coding?
It is a university question, where I have to describe and evaluate, if the codes, which are shown in our lecture notes are capable of running when using OpenJDK. 
In our lecture we are currently using Java JDK 8u112.
Topics in the lecture are for example: BufferedReader/Writer, FileReader, InputStream, ArrayList, Abstract class, Interfaces, JavaFX , JAvaFX for 2D, ...

Do you have an idea, how I can find out if the codes are working, without testing all of them on OpenJDK or without downloading and installing OpenJDK?

The only thing I found out yet is that there might be a difference in OpenJFX, and also in rastering.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Some packages are not in both versions. Example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648698/openjdk-and-com-sun-net

Comment: So, what I understand here "The java.*, javax.* and org.* packages documented in the Java Platform Standard Edition API [...] If a Java program directly calls only API in these packages, it will operate on all Java-compatible platforms, regardless of the underlying OS platform.," from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html (but again - my english is not the best) is, that there shouldn´t be a difference as long as the only packages implemented are from java.* and javafx.*, which is the case in all the programms from my lecture. is that correct?

Comment: And still, I´m not sure how to describe it. for this lecture i need to write an evaluation, to write if there is or is not a difference. But I really don´t know how to show it, if there is no difference. sorry for those questions, but I really have no idea

Comment: If you would just make the switch to the most recent version of Java (which is currently 13 and not 8) the answer to your question would be very simple. There aren't any technical differences anymore between OracaleJDK and OpenJDK. But if you insist on discussing an obsolete Java version you have to suffer the pain :-)